# switching user sessions GPG signature not work

Tags: sh, sudo, gnupg, pgp, gpg-signature

In the same terminal I need to switch user and be able to use gnugpg properly
The next script (which could also be a bash alias) to switch the terminal shell to another user.

I want running this script to ask me only the password for the sudo command

login to the new user must skip the password request:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
sudo login nextuser
```

For some reason in my case it's not enough to use: `su - nextuser` because I can't use gpg properly (probably because of gpg-agent initialization, show errors when using the signature), with the `login` command gpg-agent works fine once logged in in the new session.